# How to set countdown properly in android?

Tags: android

my countdown is running from 09 to 01 counts while i am selecting 10 from dropdown and i think it has to run till 00 count. How to resolve it ?

Comment: In order for us to help, please be very specific when asking your question and describing your problem. Include just enough code to illustrate your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a `for` loop running somewhere? The problem might be as simple as a `>` needing to be changed to a `>=`.

Comment: Probably #1 cause for something like this.